# Overflow-y is on scrollbar but drop shaddow is cut

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}

.container{
    background: black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

.smallerContainer{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50%;
    background: rgb(68, 0, 0);
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.circle {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    filter: drop-shadow(0 0 30px rgb(0, 255, 0));
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styl.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="smallerContainer">
      <img class="circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ski_trail_rating_symbol_red_circle.png">
      <img class="circle" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f1/Ski_trail_rating_symbol_red_circle.png">
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a div, where i got some little images that "glow", but they are also in another div which is set on "overflow-y: scroll;" and there the "green glow" is cut and dont want it to be cutted off please help D:

Comment: Please show us enough code so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for how to do this.

Comment: heres the code.